# HSQLDB Trigger update for LibreOffice Base

Tags: hsqldb, libreoffice-base

I am trying to create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger to stop the HSQLDB update and throw an exception, if the user enters date left input earlier than date in.

I followed the example given in the link
http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/triggers-chapt.html

But the error shows:

```
15: Unexpected end of command: REFERENCING in statement [CREATE TRIGGER checkValidDate BEFORE UPDATE ON "tblVehicles"
   REFERENCING]
```

This is my trigger statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkValidDate BEFORE UPDATE ON "tblVehicles"
   REFERENCING NEW AS newrow
FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN ATOMIC
     IF ((newrow.Hidden IS NOT NULL) AND (newrow.Date_Left < newrow.Date_In)) THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INVALID DATE ENTERED';
     END IF;
   END
```

How do I modify this statement? So is MESSAGE_TEXT a field in tblVehicles database table or just the syntax for SQLSTATE?
FYI date in and date left do not have underscores in the actual table.

UPDATE 18 March 2018:
I have installed the latest version of HSQLDB as suggested. This is the modified trigger statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "checkValidDateTime" BEFORE UPDATE ON "tblVehicles"
   REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow
FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN ATOMIC
        IF (newrow."Date Left" IS NULL) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DATE LEFT NOT ENTERED';

        ELSEIF (newrow."Time Left" IS NULL)  THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'TIME LEFT NOT ENTERED';

        ELSEIF ((newrow."Hidden" IS NOT NULL) AND (newrow."Date Left" < newrow."Date In")) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INVALID DATE ENTERED';
        ELSEIF ((newrow."Hidden" IS NOT NULL) AND (newrow."Date Left" = newrow."Date In") AND (newrow."Time Left" < newrow."Time In")) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INVALID TIME ENTERED';   
        ELSE
            UPDATE "tblVehicles" set oldrow."Hidden"='' WHERE oldrow."Id"=newrow."Id";
        END IF;
   END
```

I am not sure how to write the UPDATE command for the ELSE section. (Trigger works fine without the ELSE statement). How to pass values from LibreOffice Base front end to this trigger, such as passing the unique Id value?
 
Error code:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: wrong or missing data impact clause in declaration: MODIFIES SQL / Error Code: -5608 / State: 42608
```

Answer (score 1):

That [guide](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/) is for version 2.4.

Base comes with 1.8 built-in.  If that is what you are using, then follow [the documentation for 1.8](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/guide.html#create_trigger-section).  It looks like 1.8 does not have the REFERENCING clause.

Note that the embedded setup is [not recommended](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/FAQ_(Base)#So_why_should_I_avoid_.27embedded_databases.27.3F) except for testing.  So the preferred solution to your problem is to install version 2.4 and then *Connect to an existing database* when creating a new Base file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Jim's advice and the instructions in the linked FAQ under `How do I setup support for 'split' HSQL databases in Base?`.

Then check your column names and if they are mixed-case in the database, use double quotes as you have done with the table name. The names must be exactly the same as in the actual table. Your TRIGGER statement should work OK with the correct names.

The `MESSAGE_TEXT` is the message that is returned when the exception is thrown.